# How add item in an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend

I have this in my state:

```
fbPages:{'123':'Teste','142':'Teste2'}
```

But I need something like this dynamically:

```
async getFbPages(){
        var fbPages = {}
            await this.props.resultPosts.facebookPagesList.data.map(item => {
                fbPages.push({item.id: item.name});
            });
            this.setState({fbPages});
            console.log(this.state);
}
```

I got a error here `fbPages.push({item.id: item.name});`, how can I do this?

Comment: `fbPages` should be an array and not an object.

Comment: declare `fbPages` as an array like this: `var fbPages = []`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `push` but `fbPages` is not an array.
If you want to add another property to the object do `fbPages[item.id] = item.name;` instead

```
var fbPages = {};
await this.props.resultPosts.facebookPagesList.data.map(item => {
  fbPages[item.id] = item.name;
});
```

Unless you wanted an array to begin with, then declare it as such instead `var fbPages = []`

```
var fbPages = [];
await this.props.resultPosts.facebookPagesList.data.map(item => {
  fbPages.push({
    item.id: item.name
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find below sample snippet:

```js
const items = [{
                id:'123',
                name:'Teste'
               },{
               id: '142',
               name: 'Teste2'
             }];

let fbPages = []; // This should be array.

items.map((item)=> {
    fbPages.push({
       [item.id]: item.name
    })
});

console.log(fbPages);
```

Answer (score 0):

Object does not support push method you need to define `fbPages` to array

```
var fbPages= [];
fbPages[0] ={'123':'Teste','142':'Teste2'}
```

And in Function

```
async getFbPages(){
            var fbPages= [];
            await this.props.resultPosts.facebookPagesList.data.map(item => {
                fbPages.push({item.id: item.name});
            });
            this.setState({fbPages});
            console.log(this.state);
}
```